# Does GmailAPI service account access *require* Delegating domain-wide authority to send mail only from owner's address?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to use the GmailAPI (using OAUTH) to send emails from a Windows application to people within our company.  The emails only need to come from one address - one created specifically for this purpose.  I set up a service account and went through the process of generating credentials.  The admin approved the Auth Scopes for 'Send' and 'Compose'.

But when I attempt to send a message, I get this error:

**Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: 'Error:"invalid_request", Description:"Invalid impersonation "sub" field.", Uri:""'**

I've tried using the service account email address instead of "me" above.  When I do that, I get this error:

**Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: 'Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:""'**

I haven't yet delegated domain-wide authority to the service account.  That seems dangerous to us.  It's unclear whether doing so gives this account the ability to access everyone's email?  It seems to me that if the Google cloud project was created from the account that will be sending the emails, and if the service account is also associated with that project and same user email, then it should already have the authority to send emails from that one account.  Why would it need domain-wide access?

*Does* it need that?  Or do I have some other issue?  A lot of the examples I've found for accessing the Gmail API are outdated, and I'm not sure if I am just missing some other piece to the puzzle.  Should domain-wide delegation for the service account be necessary if I just want it to be able to send emails from that one address - the same address that created the service account?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        string[] Scopes = {GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
        string ApplicationName = "XXXXXX";

        ServiceAccountCredential credential;

        string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        string jsonfile = "xxxxxx-f2fea9069fb5.json";
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@jsonfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = (ServiceAccountCredential)
                GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).UnderlyingCredential;

            var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credential.Id)
            {
                User = "me",
                Key = credential.Key,
                Scopes = Scopes
            };
            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);
        }


        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        string plainText = "To: someone@somewhere.com\r\n" +
                           "Subject: subject Test\r\n" +
                           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n\r\n" +
                           "<h1>Body Test </h1>";

        var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
        newMsg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
        service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
```

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service accounts only work with Gmail if you are using a Gsuite domain and have set up [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings)

Also remember that using the gmail api is probably going to cost you to have the application verified. This may or may not matter if its for internal use I am not sure.